# how can i get node Element value From LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

i have a collection of service users, i want to iterate over ServiceUsers and extract value from ServiceUser, (ID, USER_NAME, UN_ID, IP, NAME)

```
 <ServiceUsers xmlns="">
  <ServiceUser>
    <ID>280334</ID>
    <USER_NAME>YVELAMGAMOIYENET12:206322102</USER_NAME>
    <UN_ID>731937</UN_ID>
    <IP>91.151.136.178</IP>
    <NAME>?????????????????????: 123456</NAME>
  </ServiceUser>
  <ServiceUser>
    <ID>266070</ID>
    <USER_NAME>ACHIBALANCE:206322102</USER_NAME>
    <UN_ID>731937</UN_ID>
    <IP>185.139.56.37</IP>
    <NAME>123456</NAME>
  </ServiceUser>
</ServiceUsers>
```

my Code looks like this, but i am getting null point exception.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml)
List<XElement> xElementList = doc.Element("ServiceUsers").Descendants().ToList();
foreach (XElement element in xElementList)
{
    string TEST= element.Element("Name").Value;

    comboBoxServiceUser.Items.Add(element.Element("Name").Value);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: You have <NAME> in xml, but querying it with .Element("Name"), it should be "NAME", it is case sensitive afaik

Comment: ^^ And I guess it _could_ return `null` ? In which case `element.Element(string).Value` would be trying to access a property of something that is null.

Comment: @SergeySosunov [is correct](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9qgV3h), voting to close as typo.

Comment: type is not a problem, getting same error.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh, if it was only a typo here, .Descendants returns all the descendant nodes, 12 nodes in this case. So NullPointerException will happen even if he fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the example from [XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) as the base for the following snippet that reads the provided xml.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceUsers));

ServiceUsers i;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    i = (ServiceUsers)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ServiceUsers")]  
public class ServiceUsers : List<ServiceUser> 
{
}

public class ServiceUser 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: can i do this for String xml? or just a file? i am getting xml from internet.

Comment: Yes, just with `using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))` - I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `doc.Element("ServiceUsers").Elements()` to get the`<ServiceUser>` elements. Then you can loop over the child values of those in a nested loop.

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (XElement serviceUser in doc.Element("ServiceUsers").Elements()) {
    foreach (XElement element in serviceUser.Elements()) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{element.Name} = {element.Value}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

Prints:

```
ID = 280334
USER_NAME = YVELAMGAMOIYENET12:206322102
UN_ID = 731937
IP = 91.151.136.178
NAME = ?????????????????????: 123456
---
ID = 266070
USER_NAME = ACHIBALANCE:206322102
UN_ID = 731937
IP = 185.139.56.37
NAME = 123456
---
```

Note: `Elements()` gets the (immediate) child elements where as `Descendants()` returns all descendants. Using `Elements()` gives you a better control and allows you to get the properties grouped by user.

You can also get a specific property like this `serviceUser.Element("USER_NAME").Value`. Note that the tag names are case sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

I think the basis of the problem is your trailing 's' to put it short, You iterate ServiceUser not ServiceUsers

Anyway this runs through fine:

```
[Fact]
public void CheckIteratorTest()
{
    var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string[] resourceNames = a.GetManifestResourceNames();
    string nameOf = resourceNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("SomeXml"));
    Assert.NotNull(nameOf);

    using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(nameOf);
    Assert.NotNull(stream);

    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    var serialized = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(serialized);

    var elemList = doc.Root.Elements("ServiceUser").ToList();
    Assert.NotEqual(0, elemList.Count);
    foreach(var serviceUser in elemList)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Name : {serviceUser.Name ?? "n.a."}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As being said: XML is case-sensitive. Next issue is `.Descendants()` returns all the descendant nodes, nested ones, etc, 12 nodes in this case. So NullPointerException will happen even if you fix a "typo".

Here is your fixed code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var xElementList = doc
    .Element("ServiceUsers") // picking needed root node from document
    .Elements("ServiceUser") // picking exact ServiceUser nodes
    .Elements("NAME")  // picking actual NAME nodes
    .ToList();
foreach (XElement element in xElementList)
{
    var TEST = element.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(TEST); // do what you were doing instead of console
}
```

Comment: Can you include the "don't use Descendants" in your answer? That was helpful information from your other comment.